# D1 mini ESP8266 no sound on speaker

Tags: esp8266, pwm, speaker

I am new to Arduino and microcontrollers, I want to make a tone with my D1 mini and a [LSM-50F](https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/I900/BL50A.pdf) speaker. But I don't get any output. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Tested it with two D1 mini boards.

This is how I wired everything:
[image]

Specifications:

```
Impedance   45 Ohm 
Power (Nominal)   0,2 W 
Power (Maximum)   0,5 W 
Resonance frequency   450 Hz
```

The D1 mini's GPIO pins have a maximum of 10 mA, so I am using a 330 Ohm resistor in series to the 45 Ohm speaker to avoid overloading.

```
I = U/R 
I = 3.3 V / 330 Ohm + 45 Ohm
I = 3.3 V / 375 Ohm
I = 8.8 mA
```

My code:

```
int Speaker = 5;

void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
tone(Speaker, 450);
delay(1000);
noTone(Speaker);
}
```

I also tried a piezo from an old computer in the same setup. Not sure if the piezo is active or passive, so I tried using:

```
digitalWrite(Speaker, HIGH); // Play a tone on an active piezo.
```

And

```
tone(Speaker, 450); // Play a tone on a passive piezo.
```

Comment: Yes! 3.3 V / 375 Ohm = 0.0088 A [conversion to mA](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=576780426&rlz=1C1VDKB_deDE974DE974&sxsrf=AM9HkKnWTyrnJukdRGYts2B024kIVB3Vqw:1698336073281&q=0,0088+A+in+mA&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNq-3yipSCAxUcg_0HHUUwCwgQBSgAegQIBxAB&biw=1920&bih=931&dpr=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are plugged into D5 and have `int Speaker = 5;`
However, D5 and 5 are actually [different things](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/3.1.2/variants/d1_mini/pins_arduino.h#L42).

```
static const uint8_t D5   = 14;
```

The plain number refers to the GPIO number of the esp8266 chip. The "D5" type numbers that are silk screened are mapped onto those. So you need `int Speaker = D5;` or alternately `int Speaker = 14; /*D5 is GPIO14*/` or you need to move the wire to the actual GPIO5 which [is labeled](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/3.1.2/variants/d1_mini/pins_arduino.h#L38C11-L38C11) `D1`.

You may find your speaker is very quiet, maybe inaudible. If you're going to try driving a speaker from a GPIO pin the piezo is a better choice. But really it would be better to have some kind of amplification. [This](https://www.murata.com/en-us/support/faqs/sound/sounder/char/sch0001) is the sort of thing I've used with piezos before. You can test that you're affecting the pin at all with a meter. You may get a weird reading, but you should at least be able to tell the difference between that and a pin you aren't trying to use.