# Why isn't pin 6 on my Adafruit Feather RP2040 being sent high when I ask it to?

Tags: pins, feather

I have an Adafruit Feather RP2040 ([pinouts](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-rp2040-pico/pinouts)) connected via pin 6 to a [relay](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2895). The code (below) triggers the relay when a separate color sensor returns "enough" red values.

The color sensor works (confirmed by the serial print statements); the on-board LED (connected internally to pin 13) lights up when it should; but I don't get any voltage on pin 6 when I should. I'm testing the voltage with a standard multimeter. If I move my connecting wire from pin 6 to pin 13, I get voltage (and the relay activates). Why doesn't pin 6 get voltage? What else can I do to diagnose the issue?

Software versions:

- Arduino.CC IDE v2.2.1 (latest)
- Arduino IDE Board manager: added https://github.com/earlephilhower/arduino-pico, version 3.6.0 (latest)
- Adafruit APDS9960 Library from https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_APDS9960, version 1.2.3, released Jan 30 of this year. According to https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_APDS9960/tags there is a version 1.2.4 released on May 12th, but since this is just the light sensor code, which is behaving correctly, I don't believe the issue lies here.

Code:

```cpp
// copied & modified from the source at: 
// https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_APDS9960/blob/master/examples/color_sensor/color_sensor.ino

#include "Adafruit_APDS9960.h"
Adafruit_APDS9960 apds;

// the pin on the feather that we're using to talk to the relay
#define PIN_TO_RELAY 6

#define BUCKET_FULL_RED 50

void setup() {
  // enable Serial communication
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // try to start the color sensor
  if(!apds.begin()) {
    Serial.println("failed to initialize device! Please check your wiring.");
  }
  else {
    // Assume success
    // Serial.println("Device initialized!");

    // we want color readings
    apds.enableColor(true);
  }

  // define the relay pin as an OUTPUT pin
  pinMode(PIN_TO_RELAY, OUTPUT);
  // start with the relay "open" AKA not running the pump
  digitalWrite(PIN_TO_RELAY, LOW);

  // use the built-in LED as an external signal for "pumping"
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // create some variables to store the color data in; unused, except for 'red'
  uint16_t red, green, blue, clear;

  // for checking the relay pin state
  int relay_pin_state = 0;

  // for extra printing
  int debug = 1;
  
  // wait for color data to be ready
  while (!apds.colorDataReady()) {
    delay(5);
  }
  // get fresh data; we only care about the red, but we have to read them all
  apds.getColorData(&red, &green, &blue, &clear);

  if (debug) {
    Serial.print("current red value is:"); Serial.println(red);
  }

  if (debug > 2) {
    relay_pin_state = digitalRead(PIN_TO_RELAY);
    if (relay_pin_state == HIGH) {
      Serial.println("steadystate: Relay pin is HIGH / enabled");
    } else {
      Serial.println("steadystate: Relay pin is LOW / disabled");
    }
  }

  if (red > BUCKET_FULL_RED) {
    if (debug) {
      Serial.println("start the pump (for 5 sec)");
    }
    
    // light up the built-in LED
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    // "close" the relay to turn on the pump
    digitalWrite(PIN_TO_RELAY, HIGH);

    if (debug > 2) {
      relay_pin_state = digitalRead(PIN_TO_RELAY);
      if (relay_pin_state == HIGH) {
        Serial.println("pumping: Relay pin is HIGH / enabled");
      } else {
        Serial.println("pumping: Relay pin is LOW / disabled");
      }
    }

    // wait for a while for the pump to do its work
    // 5 sec in ms; TODO: eventually circa 4 min 
    delay(5 * 1000);
    
    if (debug) {
      Serial.println("stop the pump");
    }

    // turn off the built-in LED
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    // "open" the relay to turn off the pump
    digitalWrite(PIN_TO_RELAY, LOW);
  }
  // no need to cycle quickly; wait 1 sec in ms
  delay(1 * 1000);
}
```

I just looked more closely at the pinouts page again, and was surprised to see the hole labeled "6" on the front is labeled "GP08" on the back, which corresponds to "GPIO8" in https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/107203. I wonder if I'm sending the "D4" pin HIGH ("GPIO6") instead of the one I'm expecting.

Comment: Before getting to far into debugging your code, make sure all your supporting software & libraries are up to date.  I've had early versions of Adafruit libraries act just terribly.

Comment: probably because you are not telling it to go high ... set all pins high ... if the pin goes high, then set 1/2 of the pins low ...etc

Comment: @st2000 good callout; I've edited the post to include the software versions I'm aware of that could impact this. If there's anything else I could check, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: @jsotola I'm confused; I'm specifically telling pin 6 to go "HIGH" with the `digitalWrite(PIN_TO_RELAY, HIGH);` line, and then telling it to go "LOW" later. The surrounding lines for the LED_BUILTIN are working correctly, so I *assumed* that telling pin 6 to go HIGH would work the same way. Maybe not?

Comment: A closer look at the pinout chart indicates that "pin 6" may not be the thing that's labeled "6"; will be retesting with pin 8.

Comment: ... and that was it. What do you all think? Close as a typo for pin "6" vs GPIO pin 8, or put up a self-answer as a warning to others?

Comment: I don't know what you should do, but this is a recurring pattern with boards where there are D-numbers and actual proper GPIO-numbers, [particularly on ESP8266 boards](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/94659/70020). You may find [this file](https://github.com/adafruit/circuitpython/blob/16c8c9a/ports/raspberrypi/boards/adafruit_feather_rp2040/pins.c#L19-L24) enlightening. The Philhower stuff may (or may not) have a map in it somewhere from D# to GPIO#

Comment: It would be nice if you put up a self-answer, preferably with a photo to make it clear how you were confused by "8" looking like "6" on a PCB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I misled you with my ignorance. I took for granted that the thing labeled "6" on the front was in fact Pin 6, but it's not:

[image: feather with pin "6" circled]

Indeed, if I turn it over, that's "GP08":

[image: reverse face of feather with the same location labeled "GP08"]

... and so my code needs to use pin 8, not pin 6.

User [timemage](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/70020/timemage) pointed out similar confusion on a recent post: [D1 mini ESP8266 no sound on speaker](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/94659/d1-mini-esp8266-no-sound-on-speaker) where the silk-screened label on the front of the board did not match the actual pin number. They additionally point out a file that I would have never stumbled upon, but demonstrates this mapping: https://github.com/adafruit/circuitpython/blob/16c8c9a739cfe0db2c712696eb340de2d7944d41/ports/raspberrypi/boards/adafruit_feather_rp2040/pins.c#L24, namely:

```
    { MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_SDA), MP_ROM_PTR(&pin_GPIO2) },
    { MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_SCL), MP_ROM_PTR(&pin_GPIO3) },
    { MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_D5), MP_ROM_PTR(&pin_GPIO7) },
    { MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_D6), MP_ROM_PTR(&pin_GPIO8) },  /* right here */
    { MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_D9), MP_ROM_PTR(&pin_GPIO9) },
    { MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_D10), MP_ROM_PTR(&pin_GPIO10) },
```

The description of [the pinout](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-rp2040-pico/pinouts) still contains some misleading information, in my opinion:

> D6/GP08 - Digital I/O pin 6. It is also SPI1 MISO, UART1 TX, I2C0 SDA and PWM4 A.

Here, it seems to me that this spot is still being called "pin 6".

Comment: Doesn't Arduino have defines for pins? E.g. can't you simply type "D6" (or "GPIO_8")? I know it used to have that...

Comment: It's a whole new world for me, Daniël! I feel like I'm slowly learning the "language" of things, and being new -- I just took things at face value. It sounds like there's a translation that happens with the `MP_QSTR_D6` term, but I don't yet know what that turns into, and if it's obvious at all that it relates to "the thing on the front of the board that says 6".

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg you linked to unrelated platform

Comment: @Juraj whoops... Seems like the library mentioned by adafruit does indeed include the pin definitions: https://github.com/earlephilhower/arduino-pico/blob/db7ba160ae238534ac1d89381748db3ed3b6dfe9/variants/generic/common.h and https://github.com/earlephilhower/arduino-pico/blob/db7ba160ae238534ac1d89381748db3ed3b6dfe9/variants/adafruit_feather/pins_arduino.h , but then it's still D8, not D6. I would've expected D6 to refer to the silk screen up-front, and translate to the correct GPIO number... Odd...

Answer (score 2):

The pin labeled as GP06 on the bottom side of the PCB is labeled as D4 on the top side of the PCB. It is pin 4.

from https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-rp2040-pico/pinouts

> D4/GP06 - Digital I/O pin 4. It is also SPI0 SCK, I2C1 SDA and PWM3 A.